# Why is my Perl program not reading from the input file?

Tags: perl, file-io, chomp

I'm trying to read in this file:

```
Oranges
Apples
Bananas
Mangos
```

using this:

```
open (FL, "fruits");
@fruits

while(<FL>){
chomp($_);
push(@fruits,$_);
}

print @fruits;
```

But I'm not getting any output. What am I missing here? I'm trying to store all the lines in the file into an array, and printing out all the contents on a single line. Why isn't chomp removing the newlines from the file, like it's supposed to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have DOS-style newlines (i.e., \r\n) in your fruits file. The chomp command normally only works on unix-style (i.e., \n.)

Comment: That was exactly it. Thank you so much. I've been banging my head against this for the past half hour.

Comment: Are you psychic? +1 for the successful guess.

Comment: `perldoc _f chomp`  : chomp removes any trailing string that corresponds to the current value of `$/`. It works well under linux (default is `\n`), windows (`\r\n`) and mac (`\r`).

Answer (score 6):

you should **always** use :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

at the begining of your scripts.

and use 3 args open, lexical handles and test opening for failure, so your script becomes:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @fruits;
my $file = 'fruits';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "unable to open '$file' for reading :$!";

while(my $line = <$fh>){
    chomp($line);
    push @fruits, $line;
}

print Dumper \@fruits;
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I'll keep it to heart.

Comment: Ooooo. Very nice. `use strict` and `use warnings` are a *must*. +1

Answer (score 3):

You're not opening any file.  FL is a file handle that never is opened, and therefore you can't read from it.

The first thing you need to do is put `use warnings` at the top of your program to help you with these problems.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add in the open file command initially to this post. It was always there in the program, I just omitted it from this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::File;
use Data::Dumper;

my $fh = IO::File->new('fruits', 'r') or die "$!\n";
my @fruits = grep {s/\n//} $fh->getlines;
print Dumper \@fruits;
```

that's nice and clean

Answer (score 0):

You should check open for errors:

```
open( my $FL, '<', 'fruits' ) or die $!;
while(<$FL>) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You should always print the errors from IO. `open() or die "Can't open file $f, $!";

2) you probably started the program from different directory from where file "fruits" is